# Is it possible to trigger webhook event when firebase user is created?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Is there a way to send webhook event to a custom URL when a Firebase user is created? So far, the only way to do this is by including Firebase functions but I'd like to avoid that dependency https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events

Comment: Using a Cloud Function is indeed the most appropriate way. Why don’t you want to use them?

Comment: I'm using Vercel serverless functions as the backend so don't want to introduce one more backend layer

Comment: Apart from executing the call to the webhook from a front-end (which is probably not a good solution) I don’t see any other alternative. You could of course regularly fetch the users list but this is a totally different (and much less efficient) approach.